# Construction of holomorphic function

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables

I was trying to construct a holomorphic function $f$ on $\mathbb{C}$ such that
$|f|^2(z)=e^{(|z|^2-\frac{1}{2})^2}$.
I will be happy if someone can give me an idea how to do that. I would like  also to see the function explicity.

Comment: There is no non-linear entire function which has constant modulus even on one circle.

Comment: Do you have a response to the answer below?

Answer (score 5):

Such a function does not exist, because the constant value $1$ of $|f(z)|^2$ on the circle $\{z\in\mathbb C\colon|z|^2=1/2\}$ is less than the value $e^{1/4}$ of $|f(z)|^2$ at the center $z=0$ of the circle, which would contradict the [maximum modulus principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle#Related_statement) if $f$ were holomorphic on $\mathbb C$.